# How to read a text file continuously with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, import, text-files

Anyone would have an idea how to read a text file (i.e. a log file being populated continuously) from SQL Server and import it **continuously** into a SQL Server table ?

I would like to use **only T-SQL**, within a stored procedure for instance.

I have not found any option in `BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET` other than to read the whole file at once. I would have to do it at once repeatedly and look for not yet imported rows.
That's a possibility but no very efficient if the file gets large.

Is it possible to read only the latest rows at each run?

Thanks !
Philippe

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `FileSystemWatcher` in order to get notified when the log file changes

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

watcher.Path = @"C:\PathOfTheLogfile";
watcher.Filter = "MyLogfile.txt"; // You can also use wildcards here.

watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);

watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // Start watching.

...

private static void Watcher_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created) {
        //TODO: Read log from beginning
    } else {
        //TODO: Read log from last position
    }
    //TODO: write to MSSQL
    //TODO: remember last log file position
}
```

Sometimes the `FileSystemWatcher` events fires when the file is still being written to. You might have to add a delay before reading the log file.

Comment: have edited the question to make it clearer: I was looking for a T-SQL only solution (if possible). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) to the text file if your file is parseable by the Jet provider.